# Snippets between desktop and laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, clipboard

The Situation:
At work, I have a nice beefy desktop running Windows Server 2008 R2 (SharePoint dev machine). My handy ThinkPad is right next to it. Every once in a while I'd like to cut and paste or share something (usually text) between the machines: for example, I might be headed out and I'd like to take send the URL I'm reading from the desktop to the laptop.

Of course I can create a share or use the Admin shares and create files to get stuff back and forth, but that seems heavyweight for what I'm thinking of. I'm thinking more along the lines of sending myself an IM.

How do you get little things from machine to machine? Keep a shared folder pinned to the taskbar? Send an email to yourself? Bookmark sync?

While on it, I'm looking for a decent multiple clipboard handler: maybe these two functions are combined in some nice little utility?

I suspect I'm missing something simple here...

Thanks...
Jamie F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try [Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/) which has a shared clipboard. I use it at work with a large desktop running multiple VMs and my laptop. Makes it easy to use both machines at the same time and then grab my laptop and go when I leave for the day.

Comment: Cool. I'm testing this out right now. I installed the latest beta and it seems a little flaky, but I'm looking at it. I'll update with more info after I decide to keep it or chuck it...

Comment: I didn't even know there was a beta. I've been running 1.2.2 which works 99% of the time, but does occasionally act weird or refuses to share the clipboard until I copy again.

Comment: The beta didn't work out so well: it kept killing all network connectivity on my desktop (Server 2008R2.) Maybe some interaction with my anti-virus. Trying the 1.2.2 version now, and it's working a lot better.

Comment: Good to hear. You might check out the latest Synergy as well since it looks like they've started moving forward again. It's multi OS which is nice, but I found it flaky on Win7 last year. http://synergy-foss.org/

Comment: Based on http://nshorter.com/blog/?p=283 and http://www.maximumpc.com/article/columns/done_murphys_law_freeware_fight_synergy_vs_input_director I didn't experiment with Synergy: I'm Windows only at work. I'll be using Input director for a while. As mentioned, 1.3 wasn't any good when I tried it, but 1.2.2 has been working fine for a few days now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

[synergy](http://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/)
I use it to use one mouse and keyboard between two computers. It also shares the system cliboard. I works across all the major OSs' like Linux, windows, OSX. Great tool save a lot of time. I even use it copy between one Linux box across to another VM running on a Linux box next door.

Comment: http://synergy-foss.org/ is the new site for the current development of Synergy.

Answer (score 0):

I use GoogleDocs as a web-based Clipboard.  Just add both computers as collaborators.